# How to change environment variables in mrjob for AWS accesskey and secretaccesskey

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-ec2, mapreduce, mrjob

How do I change the `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in mrjob to enter my own credentials for AWS? I am using the Terminal on Mac OS X.

https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have several ways. You could just change your environment variables called `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. You could probably do so using the `setenv` command, although I'm not a Mac OS expert.

A nice feature of mrjob is that it also reads a config called **mrjob.conf** and looks for it in default places such as your home directory, the /etc directory and the directory pointed to by the environment variable `MRJOB_CONF`. This config is in YAML format, so you should have a section like the following to setup your keys:

runners:
  emr:
    aws_access_key_id: XXXX
    aws_secret_access_key: YYYY
    ...

There are many more parameters you can setup in the config so I advise you look at [an example config](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/blob/master/mrjob.conf.example) to see what you can do there.

I've also read that it works if you setup your keys in your boto config in the **.boto** file under either your home directory or the /etc directory, and you can add the following lines. Not tested myself, but should work as well:

```
aws_access_key_id = XXXX
aws_secret_access_key = YYYY
```